# MPI - sending and receiving columns of matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, mpi4py

I'm trying to send matrix columns to other processes using `Scatter`. The code below works great for rows, so in order to send columns with minimal modifications, I use the Numpy transpose function. However, this seems to have no effect unless I make a full new copy of the matrix (which as you can imagine, defeats the purpose).

3 minimal examples to illustrate the problem (must run with 3 processes!) below.

1. Scatter rows (works as expected):

   ```
   comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
   rank = comm.Get_rank()
   size = comm.Get_size()

   A = np.zeros((3,3))
   if rank==0:
       A = np.matrix([[1.,2.,3.],[4.,5.,6.],[7.,8.,9.]])

   local_a = np.zeros(3)

   comm.Scatter(A, local_a, root=0)
   print "process", rank, "has", local_a
   ```

   Giving the output:

   ```
   process 0 has [ 1.  2.  3.]
   process 1 has [ 4.  5.  6.]
   process 2 has [ 7.  8.  9.]
   ```
2. Scatter columns (doesn't work, still scattering rows...):

   ```
   comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
   rank = comm.Get_rank()
   size = comm.Get_size()

   A = np.zeros((3,3))
   if rank==0:
       A = np.matrix([[1.,2.,3.],[4.,5.,6.],[7.,8.,9.]]).T

   local_a = np.zeros(3)

   comm.Scatter(A, local_a, root=0)
   print "process", rank, "has", local_a
   ```

   Giving the output:

   ```
   process 0 has [ 1.  2.  3.]
   process 1 has [ 4.  5.  6.]
   process 2 has [ 7.  8.  9.]
   ```
3. Scatter columns (works, but seems pointless):

   ```
   comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
   rank = comm.Get_rank()
   size = comm.Get_size()

   A = np.zeros((3,3))
   if rank==0:
       A = np.matrix([[1.,2.,3.],[4.,5.,6.],[7.,8.,9.]]).T.copy()

   local_a = np.zeros(3)

   comm.Scatter(A, local_a, root=0)
   print "process", rank, "has", local_a
   ```

   Finally giving the desired output:

   ```
   process 0 has [ 1.  4.  7.]
   process 2 has [ 3.  6.  9.]
   process 1 has [ 2.  5.  8.]
   ```

Is there an easy way to send columns without having to copy the whole matrix?

---

For context, I am doing exercise 5 in the [`mpi4py` tutorial](http://materials.jeremybejarano.com/MPIwithPython/collectiveCom.html). My full solution (which wastes memory as in point 3. above) is this, in case you want to know:

```
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

A = np.zeros((3,3))
v = np.zeros(3)
result = np.zeros(3)
if rank==0:
    A = np.array([[1.,2.,3.],[4.,5.,6.],[7.,8.,9.]]).T.copy()
    v = np.array([0.1,0.01,0.001])

# Scatter the columns of the matrix
local_a = np.zeros(3)
comm.Scatter(A, local_a, root=0)

# Scatter the elements of the vector
local_v = np.array([0.])
comm.Scatter(v, local_v, root=0)

print "process", rank, "has A_ij =", local_a, "and v_i", local_v

# Multiplication
local_result = local_a * local_v

# Add together
comm.Reduce(local_result, result, op=MPI.SUM)
print "process", rank, "finds", result, "(", local_result, ")"

if (rank==0):
    print "The resulting vector is"
    print "   ", result, "computed in parallel"
    print "and", np.dot(A.T,v), "computed serially."
```

---

Here is the memory profiling test requested by @Sajid:

My solution 3 (gives correct answer):

`0.027 MiB       A = np.array([[1.,2.,3.],[4.,5.,6.],[7.,8.,9.]]).T.copy()
0.066 MiB       comm.Scatter(A, local_a, root=0)`

Total = 0.093 MiB

Another similar solution (gives correct answer):

`0.004 MiB       A = np.array([[1.,2.,3.],[4.,5.,6.],[7.,8.,9.]])
0.090 MiB       comm.Scatter(A.T.copy(), local_a, root=0)`

Total = 0.094 MiB

@Sajid's solution (gives correct answer):

`0.039 MiB       A[:,:] = np.transpose(np.array([[1.,2.,3.],[4.,5.,6.],[7.,8.,9.]]))
0.062 MiB       comm.Scatter(A, local_a, root=0)`

Total = 0.101 MiB

My solution 2 (gives wrong answer):

`0.004 MiB       A = np.array([[1.,2.,3.],[4.,5.,6.],[7.,8.,9.]])
0.066 MiB       comm.Scatter(A, local_a, root=0)`

Total = 0.070 MiB

(I only copied the memory increments from the lines, where the memory increment differs between the code versions. This is all from the root node, obviously.)

It seems clear that all the correct solutions must copy the array in memory. This is suboptimal, since all I want is to scatter columns instead of rows.

---

Answer (score 1):

Might be an issue with the data not being copied to A properly, try the following :

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

A = np.zeros((3,3))
if rank==0:
    A[:,:] = np.transpose(np.matrix([[1.,2.,3.],[4.,5.,6.],[7.,8.,9.]]))

local_a = (np.zeros(3))

comm.Scatter(A, local_a, root=0)
print("process", rank, "has", local_a)
```

Of course, if you're using python2 change the print statement.

Comment: Thank you! This gives me the desired result, but doesn't it also copy the matrix in memory?

Comment: At first sight, I think that the issue was about copying the data correctly, but if you could confirm with actually profiling the two versions of the code it would be clear.

Comment: I added the memory profiling test into the original post, because it was too long to post as a comment.